# How to fill a new column with value fron existing column based on a condition?

Tags: r, coding-style

I have data as below -

I want to create a new column called "status_after_1month" where I want the values from the column Contract_Type based on the condition if the Start_date and End_Date contains any date from the month of Feb  and should populate "Churn" if the record is not found.

[image]

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure this is what you need (difficult to parse what you mean by 'should populate "Churn" if the record is not found'):

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:3,
  Start_Date = c("1/1/2020", "1/1g/2020", "1/20/2020"),
  End_Date = c("6/14/2020", "3/14/2020", "2/22/2020"),
  Contract_Type = c("VPP", "Contract", "VPP")
)
```

Solution:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
         status_after_1month = ifelse(grepl("^2", Start_Date)|grepl("^2", End_Date), 
                      Contract_Type, 
                      "Churn"))
  ID Start_Date  End_Date Contract_Type status_after_1month
1  1   1/1/2020 6/14/2020           VPP               Churn
2  2  1/1g/2020 3/14/2020      Contract               Churn
3  3  1/20/2020 2/22/2020           VPP                 VPP
```